# Master/Detail flow with only fragments

Tags: android, master-detail

I want to use Master/Detail flow in my app. I have been reading about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant.html) and also created an example project with help of Eclipse templates.

What I don't want is to use activities, like most of the examples I have been reading suggestions. I want to have only one main activity within my app and several fragments that are being replaced when user navigate through use of Navigation Drawer.

So, does anyone know how I can achieve using Master/Detail flow with only fragments? I would appreciate a code sample or tutorial or something, but any hint would be useful.

**Note!** I still want it to behave differently on handset and tablets, like described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant.html#master-detail)